# Ruby Enterprise fails to compile with GCC 4.5

Tags: gcc, segmentation-fault, archlinux

Ruby Enterprise Edition fails to compile from sources with GCC 4.5, but sucessfully compiles with 4.3.3.
Actually, not sure if it's about GCC, but, in fact, i686 Arch linux system with laest updates won't compile RE.

Compilation fails with the message:

```
mkdir -p .ext/common
make PRELIBS='-Wl,-rpath,/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib -L/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.01/lib -ltcmalloc_minimal '
./lib/fileutils.rb:1215: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-12-24 patchlevel 248) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.01

make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Aborted
```

Are there any solutions excepting GCC downgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey, updating Archlinux to the latest version fixes the problem as of now. I'm not sure what it is they changed.

The error you see is not in GCC btw, the ruby installer script attempts a File#chmod and for some reason it encounters a SEGFAULT.

Comment: You say what that is not GCC error, but File#chmod must be compiled from file.c, isn't it? If something changed, it is definitely GCC compiler and their libs (they seems changed some versions since then: 4.5.0-1 => 4.5.0-4). I think it probably was a bug in the GCC compiler.

Comment: Also, possibly I had insufficient hdd space ;)